# How to use useState in root layout/page in app directory of nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In Nextjs 13 - experimental app directory, if I wanted to use useState on the root layout/page I must add ‘use client’ to the code, which effectively prevents all nested components from being server components.. how can I work around this so that I can use useState and still have server components. Thanks to any responders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a client layout make everything client? If so, how to add client interactivities to it while keeping it a server component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801266/does-a-client-layout-make-everything-client-if-so-how-to-add-client-interactiv)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers to your question (it's better to add some example code to help users understand your problem)

If you create a Server Component, and in that component you add your Client Component, it works fine. For example

ClientComponent.tsx

```
"use client";
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function ClientComponent() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Client Component</h1>
            <p>Count: {count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

ServerComponent.tsx

```
async function getData(){
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/hello');
    return await res.json();
}

export default async function ServerComponent() {
    const data = await getData()

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Server Component</h1>
            <p>{data.name}</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Api hello.ts

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Your page

```
import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ServerComponent from "./ServerComponent";
export default function Page() {

    return(<>
            <ClientComponent/>
            <ServerComponent/>
        </>
    )
}
```

In this example ServerComponent is rendered on the server, but ClientComponent on the client so it maintain interactivity

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

> how can I work around this so that I can use useState and still have
> server components

this is not possible. server component means the initial rendering of the component occurs on the server before being sent to the client. This can improve performance by reducing the time to first render and enhancing the overall user experience. this is the whole point of server components. You are isolated from the browser. `useState` is react.js client-side specific code. it works only on the browser side. its purpose is to show the updated component to the user when the `useState` value changes.  so you cannot use `useState` on the server

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you can use "searchParams" to obtain the value. That also implies you have a button to submit the value.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params