# Does a client layout make everything client? If so, how to add client interactivities to it while keeping it a server component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to understand how to handle modals opening/closing with server components. Previously, with client components, I would just lift the state up to my `Layout`:

```js
export default function Layout({ children }) {

const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(true)

return (
<>
  <Popup showPopup={showPopup} setShowPopup={setShowPopup} />
  <div>{children}</div>
</>
)
```

And then show/hide my popup according to this state. However, with server components, I can't do that anymore. To make it work, I would need to `"use client"` at the top to make it a client component, but then the whole app would be a client component (because that's my root layout).

I want the root layout to be a server component to allow the app to leverage infrastructure toward better performance and overall user experience.

So how do you handle showing or hiding a modal without relying on useState and client components ? This case is so common that I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have client interactivities, like opening a modal, or client-specific code like `useState` without having a Client Component. That has been said,
not because `Layout` is marked as a Client Component, everything that's rendered by it will be. As you can read on the [doc](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#importing-server-components-into-client-components), you could pass a Server Component to a Client Component as part of `props`:

```js
// app/page.js

// ✅ This pattern works. You can pass a Server Component
// as a child or prop of a Client Component.
import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import ServerComponent from "./ServerComponent";

// Pages are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  );
}
```

So since your `Layout` doesn't seem to render anything else than the popup and `children`, you can make it a Client Component:

```
"use client";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Popup showPopup={showPopup} setShowPopup={setShowPopup} />
      {/* children can still be a server component */}
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

But if you have some stuff in the layout that needs to be rendered on the server, you could move the popup in a client wrapper component, like so:

```
"use client";

import Popup from "./Popup"
export default function PopupWrapper() {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(true);

  return <Popup showPopup={showPopup} setShowPopup={setShowPopup} />;
}
```

```
import PopupWrapper from "./PopupWrapper";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <PopupWrapper />
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are literally my hero

Answer (score -1):

#### Using a wrapper component

A time ago i saw somewhere in Next documentation that to use client side components in Layout you need to put the component in other file with "use client" and import it in your layout file

#### Using next's dynamic feature

if it dont work you can try to use dynamic with ssr property but i dont know if this will work

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() => import('../components/header'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```