# How to use UI libraries that utilize Providers with NextJS app router, inside server-side components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, app-router

Most recent libraries like ChakraUI, Mantine, AndD, ... require you to wrap you entire application inside a Provider component. However, by doing so, all the content created by these libraries should be used inside client-side pages.

Now imagine a web application that has 10 server-side pages that are open to all users (**which require strong SEO**), and 10 client-side pages, which will be visible after user logins.

If we want to have a consistent styling system for all these pages (both client-side and server-side), is it possible to use these UI libraries, without sacrificing the benefits of server-side rendering? And if the answer is yes what would be the best practice for doing so?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801266/does-a-client-layout-make-everything-client-if-so-how-to-add-client-interactiv.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar thanks for the comment, however I really don't think the question you are referring to answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that there is any UI Javascript library that support Nextjs13 App router SSR right now, but you can use CSS libraries that embrace react component concept like [NextUI](https://nextui.org/) or [DaisyUI](https://daisyui.com/).