# How to get localStorage item in layout.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js14

Sorry for poor English, it is my second language.

I am using Next.js 14.
I want to make a function that checks localStorage item before moving user into a specific page. Else it redirects user to the home page. (Similar to profile page requring logged in info)

However, since I am already using metdata(which runs in SSR I guess), it is not possible for me to access the localStorage without "use client". How should I fix the structure in this case? Is there way to get localStorage item here? Or is there a way to fix the page title without using metadata?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export const metadata = {
  title: "My Profile",
};

export default function StarforceProfileLayout({ children }) {
  const apiKey = localStorage.getItem("api-key");
  if (!apiKey) {
    redirect("/");
  }
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801266/does-a-client-layout-make-everything-client-if-so-how-to-add-client-interactiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store Your api-key in cookies. you have access to cookies in ssr via next/headers.

Comment: I thought next js 14 do not recommend using next/header?